# Defining an inline equation environment

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, environments

I am wondering whether it is possible to define an inline equation environment in which equations do not break when they reach document margins. Here is a MWE in which my equation breaks (prob, you need to add/remove some o)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text $f(x)=3x^2-2x+5+7$

\end{document}
```

One can claim that it is proper to use a `display` environment. However, sometimes, i want my equations to be in an inline-mode. Further, I know that i can achieve the desire outcome if i use `\mbox{}` command. More precise,

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text \mbox{$f(x)=3x^2-2x+5+7$}

\end{document}
```

So, my question is if it is possible to define an environment in which `\mbox{}` is loaded automatically instead of manually (as in the 2nd MWE). That is, `$..$`=`\mbox{$...$}`

Comment: I do not really understand what you are looking for. I mean, you could certainly write a command, say `UnbreakEq{}` which internally puts its argument within an `mbox`. But that would then require you to wrap each inline equation in `\UnbreakEq{$f(x)=3x^2-2x+5+7$}` instead of `\mbox{$f(x)=3x^2-2x+5+7$}`, which is hardly more convenient. Are you looking for a way that automatically wraps everything written as `$...$` in an `mbox`, without displaying this in the source-code?

Comment: yes exactly. I am looking for a way that automatically wraps everything written as `$...$` in an mbox, without displaying this in the source-code

Comment: I also think that the OP wants to do this if and only if the formula would be broken automatically. In other words, how to make `$ $` unbreakable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By setting `\relpenalty` and `\binoppenalty` to 10000, no inline formula can be broken across lines, unless a specific penalty item is issued: by a hard-coded rule in TeX, breaks in inline formulas can only happen *after* binary operation or relation symbols, with the penalty (that measures the desirability of a break) stated by those parameters' value, or at an explicit penalty.

```
\documentclass{article}

\relpenalty=10000
\binoppenalty=10000

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text $f(x)=3x^2-2x+5+7$

\end{document}
```

Comment: ...because breaks in in-line math content are only allowed around a `rel`ation or a `bin`ary `op`erator.